# Proving that list has exactly two sorted elements

Tags: idris

I've been trying to use `So` type to implement `SortedTwoElems` proof type and function `isSortedTwoElems`. I'm not sure how to go about implementing `proveUnsortedTwoElems` case.

Here's the full example:

```
import Data.So

data SortedTwoElems : List e -> Type where
  MkSortedTwoElems : Ord e => {x : e} -> {y : e} -> (prf : So (x <= y))-> SortedTwoElems [x, y]

proveUnsortedTwoElems : Ord e => {x : e} -> {y : e} -> So (not (x <= y)) -> SortedTwoElems [x, y] -> Void
proveUnsortedTwoElems = ?how_to_implement_this

isSortedTwoElems : Ord e => {x : e} -> {y : e} -> (xs : List e) -> Dec (SortedTwoElems xs)
isSortedTwoElems []                      = No (\(MkSortedTwoElems _)  impossible)
isSortedTwoElems (x :: [])               = No (\(MkSortedTwoElems _)  impossible)
isSortedTwoElems (x :: (y :: (z :: xs))) = No (\(MkSortedTwoElems _)  impossible)
isSortedTwoElems (x :: (y :: [])) =
  case choose (x <= y) of
    (Left prf) => Yes (MkSortedTwoElems prf)
    (Right prfNot) => No (proveUnsortedTwoElems prfNot)
```

When doing it with:

`proveUnsortedTwoElems (MkSortedTwoElems _) impossible`

type checker complains with:

`proveUnsortedTwoElems (MkSortedTwoElems _) is a valid case`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started with an intermediate lemma which should allow to conclude whenever you find two contradictory `So`s:

```
soNotTrue : So b -> So (not b) -> Void
soNotTrue {b = True}  prf prf' = absurd prf'
soNotTrue {b = False} prf prf' = absurd prf
```

You can then try to write:

```
unsortedTwoElems : Ord e => So (not (x <= y)) -> SortedTwoElems [x, y] -> Void
unsortedTwoElems prf (MkSortedTwoElems prf') = soNotTrue prf' prf
```

And here the error message should clue you in: the `Ord e` constraint used in `So (not (x <= y))` is the one bound in `unsortedTwoElems` whilst the one used inside of `MkSortedTwoElems` is bounded by it.

There is no guarantee that these two `Ord`s are compatible.

My suggested solution: redefine `SortedTwoElems` so that it is explicit about the `Ord` it is using.

```
import Data.So

data SortedTwoElems : Ord e -> List e -> Type where
  MkSortedTwoElems : {o : Ord e} -> So (x <= y) -> SortedTwoElems o [x, y]

soNotTrue : So b -> So (not b) -> Void
soNotTrue {b = True}  prf prf' = absurd prf'
soNotTrue {b = False} prf prf' = absurd prf

unsortedTwoElems : (o : Ord e) => So (not (x <= y)) -> SortedTwoElems o [x, y] -> Void
unsortedTwoElems prf (MkSortedTwoElems prf') = soNotTrue prf' prf
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `soNotTrue` is what I was missing. Also, fair point about `Ord`.